# Checkbox or Switch with 3 states

Tags: sapui5

I'm searching a mode to show the third state (indeterminate) state of a binary variable, but I can't find in

`Switch` https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Switch/properties

or `Checkbox` https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.CheckBox/properties

Is it even possible in OpenUI5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your link the third state  is used not to visualize the state of the checkbox but rather the info that the sub-checkbox are selected.

Conceptually my solution is to use another library element to show an info that can assume more that one state: the combo.box https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.ComboBox/samples

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [TriStateCheckBox](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.TriStateCheckBox.html). It has 3 [states](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.TriStateCheckBoxState.html)

1. Checked
2. Unchecked
3. Mixed

It's under sap.ui.commons ( which means it wouldn't behave as expected on mobile devices, which in turn means you can't use it in Fiori apps )